# Understanding NOAA/GFS0P25 dataset of Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, database, noaa

I'm trying to get time-series data from NOAA/GFS0P25 data set on GEE.
My code:

```
var m2 = "NOAA/GFS0P25"

var band1 = 'total_precipitation_surface'
var data_collection = ee.ImageCollection(m2);
var dataset = data_collection.filterBounds(plots)
                    .filterDate('2019-03-04', '2019-03-05')
                    .filterMetadata('forecast_hours', 'greater_than', 0) 
                    .select(band1);

print (dataset)
```

where plots is just a point with x,y (8.228528757789945,49.390447480404966).
I was expecting to get only 4 elements (1 days * 4 times)  accrotding to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_GFS0P25): *The 384-hour forecasts, with 3-hour forecast interval, are made at 6-hour temporal resolution* .
However, I received 688 elements, which makes it impossible to obtain a larger time series than one day due to the 5000 elements limit. 
A subset of the elements looks like this:
[image]

I don't understand why are there 688 elements and not 4. I also plotted the data and I got only 4 points of data as expected:
[image]

Why is this discrepancy? how can I eventually get a time series similar to the plot but not for just 1 day but for 6 months?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be a little careful with GFS data because it can get pretty confusing with the timing (as you have already seen). First, the GFS forecast is initialized 4 times a day (at 00, 06, 12, 18  hours GMT) so you get 4 forecasts per day. Next, GFS forecast interval for an individual forecast is hourly for the first 5 days then goes to 3-hour intervals up to day 10 then goes to 12-hour interval for the rest up to 16 days as shown in the returned data from your example. So, theoretically you will get 60 (24+18+12+6) images per day with different forecast times *if you keep track of all the timing*.

However, Earth Engine does not keep track of all of the timing for you. If you look at the metadata, you will see that the `system:time_start` is equal to the `creation_time` (i.e. initialization time). So, when you use `.filterDate()` in EE (which uses the `system:time_start` property internally for filtering) you only filter by the day that the forecast was created (all the forecast initialization and forecast hours) and you get (5*24+5*8+6*2)*4 which equals the 688 images from your example.

Hopefully that helps make a little more sense on how the data is structured in terms of time and now we can use that understanding to start filtering. Here is an example getting a single day from different forecasts initializations:

```
var data_collection = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/GFS0P25");

// date that we want to focus on
var forecast_date = ee.Date('2019-03-04')

// get 00Z initialization for the whole day
var forecast00 = data_collection.filterDate(forecast_date,forecast_date.advance(6,'hour'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('forecast_time',forecast_date.advance(1,'day').millis()))
print('00Z initialization:',forecast00)

// get 06Z initialization for the rest of the day
var forecast06 = data_collection.filterDate(forecast_date.advance(6,'hour'),forecast_date.advance(12,'hour'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('forecast_time',forecast_date.advance(1,'day').millis()))
print('06Z initialization:',forecast06)

// get 12Z initialization for the rest of the day
var forecast12 = data_collection.filterDate(forecast_date.advance(12,'hour'),forecast_date.advance(18,'hour'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('forecast_time',forecast_date.advance(1,'day').millis()))
print('12Z initialization:',forecast12)

// get 18Z initialization for the rest of the day
var forecast18 = data_collection.filterDate(forecast_date.advance(18,'hour'),forecast_date.advance(24,'hour'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('forecast_time',forecast_date.advance(1,'day').millis()))
print('18Z initialization:',forecast18)
```

As you can see from the example, the `.filterDate()` is done on 6-hour intervals to get a specific forecast initialization, then the collection is filtered by the forecast time (within the date of interest). I hope this helps shed some light on the GFS data in Earth Engine. There are other ways to do the filtering based on the properties but this is a good start.

FYI: The GFS data has global coverage so using `.filterBounds()` has no effect on reducing the number of images in the collection.

Comment: Thank you, that made things much clearer now